# How to convert a string to a date typ with the stylecode 104?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2019

I have a string '11.12.2020' but how to convert it to date but with the same style 11.12.2020. I know there are the format function, but I heard it need a lot of processing power and format convert the date back to string.

I tried the code (see image) but it does not work.

[SQL-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sp4D.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't covert to a date to get a string format. Here is an example of your code that puts it in the format you want.

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 104)
```

Comment: But I get a string with this code. I need a datatyp "date" and "11.12.2020'

Comment: A date or datetime or time object, underneath, is just a really big number. Formatting is not for storage, but for display. You don't need to format it IN the database, you have to format it COMING OUT of the database. Flip the way you are looking at this, and you will see what I am getting at.